# CKAN paster db init sqlalchemy programming error

Tags: python, ckan, paster

I have followed the CKAN install guide from source (http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/installing/install-from-source.html) and managed to get all the way until point 6. Create database tables.

At that stage, running `paster db init -c /etc/ckan/default/development.ini` gives the following stack trace:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/bin/paster", line 9, in <module>
        load_entry_point('PasteScript==1.7.5', 'console_scripts', 'paster')()
      File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/command.py", line 104, in run
      invoke(command, command_name, options, args[1:])
      File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/command.py", line 143, in invoke
      exit_code = runner.run(args)
      File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/command.py", line 238, in run
      result = self.command()
      File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/lib/cli.py", line 208, in command
      self._load_config(cmd!='upgrade')
      File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/lib/cli.py", line 164, in _load_config
      self.site_user = logic.get_action('get_site_user')({'ignore_auth': True}, {})
      File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/logic/__init__.py", line 424, in wrapped
      result = _action(context, data_dict, **kw)
      File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/logic/action/get.py", line 2209, in get_site_user
      user = model.User.get(site_id)
      File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/model/user.py", line 64, in get
      return query.first()
      File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2334, in first
      ret = list(self[0:1])
      File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2201, in __getitem__
      return list(res)
      File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2405, in __iter__
      return self._execute_and_instances(context)
      File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2420, in _execute_and_instances
      result = conn.execute(querycontext.statement, self._params)
      File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 727, in execute
      return meth(self, multiparams, params)
      File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 322, in _execute_on_connection
      return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
      File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 824, in _execute_clauseelement
      compiled_sql, distilled_params
      File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 954, in _execute_context
    context)
      File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1116, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    exc_info
      File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 189, in raise_from_cause
      reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb)
      File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 947, in _execute_context
    context)
      File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 435, in do_execute
      cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) column user.password does not exist
    LINE 1: SELECT "user".password AS user_password, "user".id AS user_i...
                   ^
     'SELECT "user".password AS user_password, "user".id AS user_id,     "user".name AS user_name, "user".openid AS user_openid, "user".fullname AS user_fullname, "user".email AS user_email, "user".apikey AS user_apikey, "user".created AS user_created, "user".reset_key AS user_reset_key, "user".about AS user_about, "user".activity_streams_email_notifications AS user_activity_streams_email_notifications, "user".sysadmin AS user_sysadmin, "user".state AS user_state \nFROM "user" \nWHERE "user".name = %(name_1)s OR "user".openid = %(openid_1)s OR "user".id = %(id_1)s ORDER BY "user".name \n LIMIT %(param_1)s' {'param_1': 1, 'id_1': 'default', 'name_1': 'default', 'openid_1': 'default'}`

I did not make any modifications to the installation or the schema. The installation is under a proxy, but that did not turn out to be a problem thus far, since there were many posts giving help in that regard.

Did anybody come across this error before and managed to resolve it? I don't suppose it is a proxy-related problem... though it seems to be related to the schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to solve this one after all, so I'll answer my own question... :)

The problem was with the setup of the database. Once I purged the database
and completely reinstalled it, everything worked like a charm!

Comment: Similar happened to me when installing ckan. I think I just entered some cmds in the wrong order in my case.

I had to drop the database `sudo -u postgres dropdb ckan_default` then `sudo -u postgres psql -l` to make sure it was dropped. Then re-run the create command `sudo -u postgres createdb -O ckan_default ckan_default -E utf-8`.  After that I was able to successfully run `paster db init -c /etc/ckan/default/development.ini` to create db tables.

Comment: Hi Flashpoint, could you please explain how exactly did you purge the database. I use this command: paster db clean -c /etc/ckan/default/development.ini, but still get the same error....

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue but dropping the DB and creating and initialising it again afterwards produced the same error. Also running `paster db clear -c /etc/ckan/default/development.ini` failed with said error.

It worked for me, when I deactivated all `ckan.plugins` in `development.ini` before running `paster db init -c /etc/ckan/default/development.ini`.

Comment: Also having the same issue. you can not create a ckan database with ini file that contains plugins that also create tables in the database. its like it initailizes the plugins first before creating the database.

Answer (score 1):

> sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) column user.password does not exist
>   LINE 1: SELECT "user".password AS user_password, "user".id AS user_i...

This error usually means that the CKAN database exists but is empty - the CKAN tables have not been created in it.

To solve it:

```
cd /usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan
paster db init -c /etc/ckan/default/development.ini
```

There's more about this in the docs:
http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/installing/install-from-source.html#create-database-tables